How to prove the formula bounding the ratio of some Jacobi function and the modulus of the Jacobi's elliptic integral of the first kind?
I am studying the problem of finding the zeros to a fifth degree polynomial equation. Apparently, it can be expressed with some Jacobi's elliptic function. However a given formula is given me hard time to sleep. I have looked for its proof in some books but I am not very into Number theory so I don't where to find the proof. Can someone tell where it is ? Or if the proof is simple ?
Here, is the problem.
We define two theta functions :
$$ \theta_2(q)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} q^{(n+1/2)^2}$$
$$ \theta_3(q)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2}$$
And we define the following things relative to the elliptic functions of Jacobi :
$$ k\in ]0,1[$$
$$ k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$$
$$ K=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\varphi}}$$
$$ K'=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k'^2\sin^2\varphi}}$$
$$ q=e^{-\pi K'/K}$$
Then the formula, I am looking for a proof, can be stated as follows :
$$ k=\dfrac{\theta_2(q)^2}{\theta_3(q)^2} $$
Thank you,
Charles

The proof is a bit complicated and requires studying properties of elliptic integral $K$ as well as those of theta functions. I have discussed this in detail in my blog posts https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html?m=0 and  https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0

Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Something is quite unclear to me from your calculations. You obtained a close formula for q considered as a free parameter, but I don’t see exactly how can one obtain a close formula for k the moduli given your calculations. Can you elaborate on this ? It would greatly help.

Yes the blog post starts with a $q\in(0,1)$ and then defines $k=\vartheta_2^2(q)/\vartheta_3^2(q)$ and then shows that $q=\exp(-\pi K'/K) $. But then the relation between $q, k$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to itself (prove this) so all the steps are reversible.

Also see this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4779031/72031 which gives Ramanujan's approach to deal with your problem. Here we start with $k$, define elliptic integrals and $q$ and then show $k$ as a ratio of theta functions.

Thank you so much for your answers. I am going to study the Ramanujan’s approach you just gave. I guess the functions theta are monotone in a good way to obtain the wanted bijection. By the way, did you know Abel and Jacobi were said by Gauss to have gone one third towards the theory of elliptic functions ?

I have read with a lot of attention your post. And I must admit that something is not very clear for me at least in the proof of Ramanujan. Indeed, you used the second identity numbered (6) to show the first one. Is there a simple proof of this equality ? Namely, and based on your notations $$ z=\phi(q)^2$$

I think that the best approach as per your post would be to prove the bijection between $q, k$ directly by showing that $\frac{dq} {dk} =\frac{\pi^2q}{2kk'^2K^2}$ which is positive. The above differentiation formula requires the formulas for derivatives of elliptic integrals.

Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to obtain the formula you gave to me. However, I am stuck because it would need to show something like : $$ EK’+E’K-KK’=\pi$$ Is this a common formula in the field ?

Well the identity $EK'+E'K-KK'=\frac{\pi} {2}$ is famous by name Legendre's identity. A proof is available in my blog post https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-legendres-identity.html?m=0

Thank you very much for all your answers. This helped me a lot. I think I am ready to prove what I needed now. I have a curiosity question however and I hope you have the answer. In a Hermite's article, $\phi: \omega \mapsto \dfrac{\theta_2(e^{i\omega})}{\theta_3(e^{i\omega})}$ is under consideration ... A very simple formula is given to get $\phi(\omega+1)$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\phi(-1/\omega)=\sqrt{k'}$. Have you any idea how to get this formula ? Thank you very much.
Charles Ladmiral
